# how to make a copy from csv file to edit it

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i'm trying to make a copy from csv file to edit it away of the original
then I apply the effects to the original

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

filename = "data1.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
print(temp_file.name)
with open(filename, "r",encoding='utf8') as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ["id", "name", "email", "sent"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    # writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow({
            "id":row["id"],
            "name":row["name"],
            "email":row["email"],
            "sent":""
        })
```

I get this error :/

```
C:\Users\Arafat\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwgkcslas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arafat\Desktop\30dpython\hungry_data.py", line 49, in <module>
    "sent":""
  File "C:\Users\Arafat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Arafat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the result of your temp_file being opened in binary mode rather than text mode (the default is `w+b`). Change it to:

```
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', encoding='utf8', delete=False)
```

(the encoding is not strictly necessary, but since you're specifying it on the input, makes sense to specify it on the output).

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: You should also add a `newline=''` keyword argument to the `open()` calls as described in the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents). This is because `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` use  an underlying `csv.reader` or `csv.writer` instance to actually read or write to the file (and those require this argument in Python-3.x).

Comment: THANKS ALOT  IT WAS HELP FULL and the Problem Solved :D